# PHP preg_match_all return empty

Tags: php, preg-match

This is my code:

```
$str = "sdf13631389945fssx6221363138994523213af";
preg_match_all("/^1\d{10}$/",$str,$result);
var_dump($result);
```

I want to match the phone no. 13631389945 but don't want to match this phone no. in 6221363138994523213 , so I write this, but it return empty, can you help me write a right pattern, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't return a result because the whole string doesn't match the expression. If you only want part of the string to match then get rid of the `^` and `$`.

```
preg_match_all("/1\d{10}/",$str,$result);
```

To not match the phone number in the second part of the string you are going to have to explain what exactly makes it an invalid match. If it's the surrounding numbers then use this:

```
(?:^|[^\d])(1\d{10})(?:$|[^\d])
```

Comment: But if I get rid of ^ $, just write what you say, it will return all the13631389945 include the no. in 6221363138994523213, it's what I don't want to, I just want to match the first no.

Comment: @killua0083 So tell us why it should not return the second one. If it's simply the fact it has other numbers around it then only match things that don't have a number on either side: `(?:^|[^\d])(1\d{10})(?:$|[^\d])`

Comment: Because I want to count the phone No. , the 6221363138994523213 is not the phone No. it shouldn't be counted

Comment: @killua0083 That doesn't explain it at all. What makes "13631389945" a phone number the first time in the string that doesn't also apply to "13631389945" the second time?